# How to show dates in a chart in Excel?

Tags: excel, date, charts

My date data in x axis is in this format: 11/15 (without year).
How to show dates in a chart from 15Nov to 29Apr in Excel?
Below chart is not correct. The first dates have moved to end.

[image]

Comment: please say what you see in formula bar when you select one dates? e.g. is it `11/15/2017` for 15-Nov?

Comment: @S.Serp yes. I see 11/15/2017

Comment: Maybe showing a screenshot of your sample data will help.

Answer (score 0):

I converted dates to text using: =TEXT(B2,"mm/dd") for all of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Excel will add a default year (current year) for you when you enter just the month and day. so 15-Nov is actually 15-Nov-2017, and 29-Apr will also be 29-Apr-2017. So the 29-Apr will be assumed sooner than 15-Nov. I know you want 15-Nov for previous year and 29-Apr for next year but excel does no know your meaning..

So, you have to **add the year part to your dates** (even manually or using an formula) to specify exact order of dates and then use a format string to hide year in your cells like as `mmm/dd`.

Comment: This problem also is in Report Viewer.

Comment: i can't get what do you mean exactly by that? did you solve your excel problem?