# How to show dates in a chart in Report Viewer?

Tags: c#, charts, reportviewer

I asked a question

[How to show dates in a chart in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41868265/how-to-show-dates-in-a-chart-in-excel)

I solved that in Excel, But I have the same problem in Report Viewer. It shifts data (related to the previous year) to the right side of the chart.
My date data is in string format.

```
List<Report> tempList = new List<Report>();

foreach (DataRow row in DT.Rows)
{
    Report temp = new Report();//class
    temp.Row = Convert.ToInt16(row["Row"].ToString());
    temp.Date = row["Date"].ToString();
    temp.Value= Convert.ToDouble(row["Value"].ToString());
    tempList.Add(temp);
}

Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource reportDataSource1 = new           Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource();
string reportEmbeddedResource = "ETc.Report1.rdlc"; 

reportDataSource1.Name = "DataSet1";
reportDataSource1.Value = this.ReportBindingSource;
this.reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource1);
this.reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = reportEmbeddedResource;

this.ReportBindingSource.DataSource = tempList;

this.reportViewer.RefreshReport();
```

Answer (score 0):

OK.
In 'Category Group Properties...' --> in 'Sorting' section, change sort type (if you have a uniqe value for each row) or delete it.